# How do I programmatically populate switch case values?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, switch-statement, programmatically-created

I am pulling in a list of allowed system codes for my case statement via JSON. They are brought in as a string that looks like the following:

```
let validCodesFromJson:String = "001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 007, 008, 090, 091, 092, 096"
```

I then convert this string into an array with the follwing:

```
let validCodes:NSArray = validCodesFromJson.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
```

I need to get this array of codes into the first case of my switch statement.

```
switch responseArray[selectedResponseTableRow]["code"]! {
        case validCodes:

            successfulPostAnimation()

        case "006":

            showAlertWindow("Alert", message: "Code was 006", buttonText: "OK")

        default:

           showAlertWindow("Alert", message: "Code was not in the list", buttonText: "OK")
        }
```

The switch statement works if the code is "006" in every other case it is using default. It works fine if I define all of the codes in the first case instead of using the array. But I need to do this programmatically for this project.

Comment: Note that the string in `componentsSeparatedByString` should be `,<blank> ` and not `<blank>,`

Comment: Noted and fixed in the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `guard-clause` to increase the complexity of your expression for each particular `case`. For example:

```
var validCodes = ["001", "002", "003"]

var code = "002"

switch code {
    case let value where (contains(validCodes, value)):
        "Valid code"
    case "006":
        "Bad code"
    default:
        "Default"
}
```

If you run this in a playground, you'll see `"Valid code"`.

If you're interested in seeing the grammar/syntax for these kinds of patterns, you can [The Swift Programming Language: Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html)

Comment: I don't think you need breaks.. ?

Comment: You're right @Rob, breaks removed. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID137)

Comment: With Swift 3 I would write the case-condition like this:
`case let value where validCodes.contains(value):`